# NSTreeController, NSOutlineview and Core Data

Tags: xcode, core-data

I'm finding a little lost trying to populate a NSOutlineView from an NSTreeController, I can see the tree with data but the leaf nodes have the same data as the parent.

I've read a ton of references to this but I feel a little overheated and can't figure out what I'm not understanding.

My model is:

-- File
 -- Figures (contents of file)

I cant post images directly cause I have not enough reputation ^^.

Model relationship [scr1](https://skitch.com/rubs/etib4/partenon-file-handler.xcodeproj-partenon-file-handler-model.xcdatamodel)

TreeController managedObjectContext bindings:

-- Key Paths -> Children: lineas
 -- Object Controller -> Mode: Entity Name -> Entity Name: File -> Prepares Content

NSOutlineView tablecell bindings

-- Bindings Value -> TreeController -> Controller Key: fecha

Result [src2](https://skitch.com/rubs/etidd/partenon-file-handler)

I thank you all in advance!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you don't set the predicate to filter out the children.
With treecontroller selected in Interface Builder, in attribute inspector, set the predicate text field to, for example, parent == nil

Comment: Five years after posting and still relevant :)